# DPM 2012 R2 Server Migration - New Hardware

Tags: backup, scdpm

I have 2 DPM 2012 R2 servers (both physical with internal storage), one onsite (DPM1) and one offsite (DPM2).

I need to migrate my onsite DPM server (DPM1) to a new machine. This is currently a server with 6TB of disk storage. The new server has 18TB of internal disk storage.

This is currently our primary DPM server with our offsite server acting as a secondary DPM server. (It looks to the primary server and takes copies of the data from that).

Is there an easy way to migrate my DPM installation from it's currently hardware to the new hardware, including its storage (ie, currently recovery points / backups)?

I can see some steps here that outline how to move the DPM DBs to the new machine: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757865(v=sc.12).aspx

I've also found these instructions that refer to a poweshell script that can move data from different disks within the same pool: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2009/06/21/how-to-use-the-migratedatasourcedatafromdpm-p...

I'm looking for a way (if possible) of copying the data from the DPM1 internal storage to the new, replacement server's internal storage.

I envisioned taking a backup of my primary DPM server DBs, standing up the new server side by side with this current DPM server, somehow copy the recovery points/data from DPM1 to the new machine, shutdown the original DPM server and then restore the DBs to the new machine. The new machine would then have the DPM DBs and data from the original DPM machine.

With regards to the storage though, my concern is that my new storage won't be in the same storage pool as the original so I may not be able to migrate my current backups across.

The scenario I'm trying to avoid is having to start our DPM backups entirely from scratch. IE, full snapshots/recovery points of our VMs (6TB+) to the new local DPM server (not too bad since it is 10Gbps) and then push that to our offsite DPM server over WAN (only 100Mbps). This will take days to get offsite.

Does anyone know if migrating current backups / recovery points from one DPM machine to another can be done?

Are there any special steps required when replacing the primary DPM server? Will I need to configure the secondary (offsite) DPM server to accept the new machine as the new primary DPM server?

(Failing that, is there anyway of performing a manual data transfer between DPM servers like you can with initial Hyper-V replicas? ie, can I create new full backups on the new DPM server and them somehow get the recovery points / data across to the secondary server via a USB drive?)